# How to change index of nested Object in an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested-object

I am trying to figure out a way to change the index of an object which has some other objects also with keys.
suppose I want to pass key to a function as 3(C) then I want to find a key in an object which is same as 3(C) and make its index as 0

I tried to use hasOwnProperty but it always gives me only true when I pass 3(C). I tried most of the things but it fails in case of nested arrays

```
{
  "1(C)": {
    "STORE (06:00 )": [
      {
        "personId": "---",
        "scheduledEventId": "----",
        "employeeName": "----.",
        "phoneNumber": "-----",
        "ranking": "-----",
        "perAph": "----",
        "distPerAph": "--",
        "distanceToEvent": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
"3(C)": {
    "THUdx (06:00 )": [
      {
        "personId": "---",
        "scheduledEventId": "----",
        "employeeName": "----.",
        "phoneNumber": "-----",
        "ranking": "-----",
        "perAph": "----",
        "distPerAph": "--",
        "distanceToEvent": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The expected result should have 3(C) object at index 0

```
{
"3(C)": {
    "THUdx (06:00 )": [
      {
        "personId": "---",
        "scheduledEventId": "----",
        "employeeName": "----.",
        "phoneNumber": "-----",
        "ranking": "-----",
        "perAph": "----",
        "distPerAph": "--",
        "distanceToEvent": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  "1(C)": {
    "STORE (06:00 )": [
      {
        "personId": "---",
        "scheduledEventId": "----",
        "employeeName": "----.",
        "phoneNumber": "-----",
        "ranking": "-----",
        "perAph": "----",
        "distPerAph": "--",
        "distanceToEvent": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: *"index"* in an object? please add your try and the wanted result.

Comment: Can you add the code you are trying to execute?

Comment: @NinaScholz I wanted to make this first key in an object like i showed it above

Comment: @IkhlaqKhan That's what an array is for.  You cannot guarantee of the order of properties stored in an object

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)[0]` is the key you're looking for?

Comment: You [can't change the order of the keys in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: @kobe is there anything we can do on objects

Comment: @VLAZ can we remove all other objects which do not match with passed keyname

Comment: Yes, you can. Then you'd be left with an object with a single key. Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth taking a step back - *why* do you want the keys to be in a specific order? And does this have to be an object? You can use an array or `Map` to guarantee order.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing something in the wrong way, and it would not be possible to do what you are trying to accomplish according to standards.

However, at least in Chrome, where order of keys in objects seems to be defined by order of defining the keys, something like that is possible by creating a new object, copying the member you want to have at 0th position first, and then copying all the remaining members.

```
function moveToFirst(src, key) {
  var keys = Object.keys(src);
  var temp = {};
  temp[key] = src[key];
  for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; ++k){
    if (keys[k] !== key) {
      temp[keys[k]] = src[keys[k]];
    }
  }
  return temp;
}
var foo = {c: "1", a: 5, bar: "lol"}
foo = moveToFirst(foo, "a");  // {a: 5, c: "1", bar: "lol"}
```